# C++ Vector of class objects

Tags: c++

I have a class called Movie with the following private data members:

```
private:
    string       title_ ;  
    string       director_ ;  
    Movie_Rating rating_ ;  
    unsigned int year_ ;  
    string       url_ ;  
    vector<string> actor_;
```

It also contains the following copy constructor:

```
Movie::Movie(Movie& myMovie)  
{  
    title_ = myMovie.title_;  
    director_ = myMovie.director_;  
    rating_ = myMovie.rating_;  
    year_ = myMovie.year_;  
    url_ = myMovie.url_;  
    actor_ = myMovie.actor_;  
}
```

When I try to create a vector of this class,

```
vector<Movie> myMovies;
```

and then accept all the info from a user into a temp `Movie` object (`myMovie1`), and then use push back:

```
myMovies.push_back(myMovie1);
```

I get the following error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector(1233) : error C2558: class 'Movie' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'
```

Where am I going wrong? It seems it wants a copy constructor but I do have one defined.

Comment: The idiomatic copy constructor signature is `Movie::Movie(const Movie& myMovie)`... you'd better put a "s" to `actor_`, there are several of them... you'd better leave the compiler automatically generate the copy constructor since there isn't any special logic there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it's protesting against binding a temporary to a non-const reference.  Try `Movie::Movie(const Movie & myMovie)` as the signature to your copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Code should read:

```
Movie::Movie(const Movie& myMovie)
{
title_ = myMovie.title_;
director_ = myMovie.director_;
rating_ = myMovie.rating_;
year_ = myMovie.year_;
url_ = myMovie.url_;
actor_ = myMovie.actor_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements that go in a `vector`must meet the "copy constructible" requirement; that is, they must have a copy constructor available. Now, is your copy constructor private or protected?

In C++11, a `vector` can also take objects that are movable, although they still need to be copyable if you want to copy the `vector`.

Comment: The Standard allows copy constructors to either take const or non-const references, although the former is far more common in practice.  A function that takes a non-const reference can't take temporaries or const objects as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Change copy constructor to

```
Movie::Movie(Movie const& myMovie)
```

or remove it completely - it seems that default(shallow copy) is ok in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the point that there is a couple of members that are objects. Surely, a default constructor performs a deep copy and respects object semantics.

Comment: It makes a member-wise copy, where the members automatically take care of deep copying. The user-defined constructor is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You copy constructor needs to be like this:

```
Movie::Movie(const Movie& myMovie)
```

The `const` is needed for the compiler to find it.